# Inputting a string with spaces in C

Tags: c, string, multidimensional-array, scanf

I want my program to prompt the user for how many sentences they want to write and then enter those sentences. However, when I try entering the sentences, I keep getting errors. I tried using several different fucntions but all of them gave some kind of error. For example, right now I am trying to use fgets() and after I enter the first sentence it gives me a segmentation fault. Can someone tell me what is the best way to take input for a string with spaces and how to fix my problem?

```
int n;
char str[n][80];

printf("Enter number of lines: ");
scanf("%d", &n);

printf("Enter a sentecne: ");
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    fgets(str[i], 80, stdin);
    printf("%s", str[i]);
}
```

Comment: you define a char array with an unitialized variable.

Comment: Not testing the return value from scanf and fgets is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 3):

You define the array `str` before you initialize `n`. That means `n` will have an *indeterminate* value (which will be seemingly random).

Move the input of `n` to *before* you define `str`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use read function http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html

reading on the file descriptor 0 (standart input), a char *buffer to store your data, and a size_t size to read

there are several problems in your code

```
int n; // must have a value
int n = 10; // example, here your variable is initialized
```

you also don't check the return value of scanf